# incremeting a value by cascading calls

Tags: c++, increment

Can someone please explain this piece of code ? I don't understand how the value of c2 is only 1.

```
    class Test
{
private:
    static int c1;
    int c2 = 0;
public:
    Test fun();
    int getC1() { return c1; }
    int getC2() { return c2; }
};
int Test::c1 = 0;
Test Test::fun()
{
    c2 += ++Test::c1;
    return *this;
}
int main()
{
    Test t;
    Test t2 = t.fun().fun().fun().fun();
    cout << t.getC1() << " " << t.getC2();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: i did it but the problem is everything happens in one line ( t2 = t.fun.fun... )

Comment: Which `c2`? Your program creates about 6 of them.

Comment: the c2 of objet t. shouldn't it be 10 ? because calling 4 times fun() on t should increment c2 like : c2 += 1 , c2+= 2, c2+=3, c2+= 4. which gives c2 = 10 for me .

Comment: You're only calling `fun()` once on `t`.

Comment: oh yeah right it's by value thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fun()` returns a **copy** of the object it is called on. The next call is on the return value.

That is, this code:

```
Test t2 = t.fun().fun().fun().fun();
```

is equivalent to this code:

```
Test temp1 = t.fun();
Test temp2 = temp1.fun();
Test temp3 = temp2.fun();
Test t2 = temp3.fun();
```

`fun()` increments the c2 variable of the instance it is called on, then returns a copy. This means that the first call increments the value of `t`, the second that of `temp1`, the third of `temp2`, etc. The copy that is created has the same `c2` value as the source.

So as you can see, `t.c2` is only incremented once.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please explain this piece of code ? I don't understand how
>   the value of c2 is only 1.

I prefer gdb, but I resist anonymous instances combined with (compiler provided) default ctor,dtor,etc.  Seems to be no place to put a break point or cout or to step into ... too much work at assy level.

An alternative you might consider is to add some diagnostic cout's ... along with copy and move ctors and dtor with diagnostic couts.

Perhaps:

---

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
private:
   int        m_seq;
   int        c2;
   static int c1;

public:
   Test()                    // default ctor
      : m_seq(++M_seq)
      , c2 (0)
      {
         std::cout << "\n  ctor  " << show() << std::flush;
      }

   Test(const Test& rhs)     // copy ctor
      : m_seq(++M_seq)       // unique seq id
      , c2 (rhs.c2)
      {
         std::cout << "\n  cctor " << show() << std::flush;
      }

   Test(const Test&& rhs)    // move ctor       (4)
      : m_seq(++M_seq)       // unique seq id
      , c2 (rhs.c2)
      {
         std::cout << "\n  mctor " << show() << std::flush;
      }  // tbd - new to me, should this be something with std::move() ?

   ~Test()                   // default dtor
      {
         std::cout << "\n  dtor  " << show() << std::flush;
      }

   Test fun();

   int getC1() { return c1; }
   int getC2() { return c2; }

   std::string show()
      {
         std::string s;
         s = " show()  seq: " + std::to_string(m_seq)
            + "    c1: " + std::to_string(c1)
            + "    c2: " + std::to_string(c2);
         return (s);
      }

public:
   static int M_seq; // diagnostic only

private:
   // coding standard - disallow when not used
   Test& operator= (const Test&)  = delete; // copy assignment (5)
   Test& operator= (const Test&&) = delete; // move assignment (6)

};

int Test::c1    = 0;
int Test::M_seq = 0;

Test Test::fun()
{
   c2 += ++Test::c1;

   // diagnostic only
   std::cout << "\n  fun() " << show() << std::flush;

   return *this;
}

int main(int, char**)
{
   // confirm initial seq state
   std::cout << "\n  -- init M_seq " << Test::M_seq << std::endl;

   Test t;

   Test t2 = t.fun().fun().fun().fun();

   std::cout << "\n\n   t final " << t.show() << std::endl; 
   std::cout <<  "\n  t2 final " << t2.show() << std::endl;
   // note how easy to ignore getters - 
   // see http://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html

   // final seq state
   std::cout << "\n\n  - final M_seq " << Test::M_seq << std::endl;
}
```

---

with output:

```
  -- init M_seq 0

  ctor   show()  seq: 1    c1: 0    c2: 0
  fun()  show()  seq: 1    c1: 1    c2: 1
  cctor  show()  seq: 2    c1: 1    c2: 1
  fun()  show()  seq: 2    c1: 2    c2: 3
  cctor  show()  seq: 3    c1: 2    c2: 3
  fun()  show()  seq: 3    c1: 3    c2: 6
  cctor  show()  seq: 4    c1: 3    c2: 6
  fun()  show()  seq: 4    c1: 4    c2: 10
  cctor  show()  seq: 5    c1: 4    c2: 10
  dtor   show()  seq: 4    c1: 4    c2: 10
  dtor   show()  seq: 3    c1: 4    c2: 6
  dtor   show()  seq: 2    c1: 4    c2: 3

   t final  show()  seq: 1    c1: 4    c2: 1

  t2 final  show()  seq: 5    c1: 4    c2: 10


  - final M_seq 5

  dtor   show()  seq: 5    c1: 4    c2: 10
  dtor   show()  seq: 1    c1: 4    c2: 1
```

> Value of c2 is only 1

This output lists the ctor, fun(), and cctor invocations.

Each anonymous object now prints its unique m_seq, so the seq id should help to see where the 'actions' take place.

The first ctor gets seq of 1 ... the first fun() is also seq 1 - make sense.

Subsequent invocations of fun() are in a different instance, the last 3 are anonymous, which makes debugging confusing.

You are correct - the first instance (with seq 1) ends with c2 value 1.  No later fun() changes it.

You are also correct, the last instance (with seq 5) ends with c2 value 10.

In the sequence of 4 fun() chained together, the last 3 create 'temporary' anonymous instances of Test, and 2, 3, and 4 dtor on the same line as they ctor.

This technique (of instrumenting your code with diagnostic couts) is common.  Precede any diagnostic cout with a bool to enable / disable for more formal testing ... precede with an bool identifier to make it easy to find / remove if you do not wish to ship with the noise.  (In production code, I have used a ram-based-round-robin log.  To ship, this log is suppressed at system startup, and the absence of the log cancels the extra cout activity.)

You could really change the behavior of this code by having Test::fun() return the pointer to an instance: Test*.  The function currently returns a Test instance (i.e. *this), thus the compiler generates a cctor to construct that new anonymous instance.  Returning the this pointer changes the fun() chain to fun()->fun()->fun()->fun().

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the detailed response ! very clear now.